# re-authenticate firebase user based on the sign-in method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my current Flutter Firebase app, I have added the option to delete the account. My app supports four types of sign-in methods: email and password, Google, Facebook, and Microsoft. Calling the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.delete()` method, as the documentation states, will throw a `FirebaseAuthException` with the `requires-recent-login` error code, which in turn, requires the user to re-authenticate as stated in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user). So for re-authentication, the following line of code should be used:

```dart
await user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
```

Now my question is, how can I create the proper credential, based on the ***current sign-in method***?

Comment: Are you asking [how to determine which provider the user is signed in with?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bflutter%5D+determine+provider)